# WPF User Controls and Windows Form User Control in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF so I have a question .

I have a windows application project that contains a WPF UserContorl ( called PaintingArea) 
which has to communicate with a WindowsFormUserControl ( called Keyboard ) .

The " PaintingArea" is hosted in  a parent form using an ElementHost1.
Now, the "keyboard"  will have to appear when I finish drawing a text box in " PaintingArea".

Is there anyway that I can make the "PaintingArea" invoke(call) the " Keyboard" (WPF UserControl calling WindowsFormUserControl) ? and vise verca?

Should I use Event Handlers?How?

Or convert the " Keyboard" to a wpf UserControl then try to call it from "PaintingArea" (A WPF UserControl call another WPF UserControl)?How?

What is the best approach to do such communication?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to host a WPF-Usercontrol in Windows Forms application, you can use the control [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx). This control has a property called Child to which you can assign an instance of an UIElement.

Furthermore, if you are looking for good examples, [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26311/Integrate-WPF-UserControls-in-WinForms) has one.

Comment: Yes , thank you .
I had a little problem when I tried to do that .It seems like my " PaintingArea" doesn't recognize or see any children ! 

I will see the link and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry ,it didn't help.

I have a problem with my painting area , it can not see any other component !

How can I be able to call a WindowsFormUserControl ( Keyboard) , from the WPF UserControl (PaintingArea)??

Please, help !

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx : A walk-through for hosting wpf control in windows form. hope it help. PS: I don't have much idea what problems you are facing, because you have not provided any code yet.